# What could be done to improve this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A few weeks ago I posted a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166250/python-prng-steganography-lsb-method) to this site. I thought I was getting low views so I even put up a bounty for this question. Now after the bounty is almost ended, I still have no comments or answers.

Thus my questions are:

1. Is my question badly formatted/too long?
2. How can I improve this question if it is not well-formatted?
3. Are general styling questions on topic here?
4. I edited my question before I put up a bounty, I read somewhere [(source)](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7329/can-i-correct-an-error-in-my-own-code) this is actually not allowed. Is that what happened here?

I'm still a beginner in Python, and I would love an answer to improve the program.

Comment: See also [How can I make my question get more attention?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6822/31562)

Comment: @SimonForsberg Thank you for your reaction. In the current state of my question how many Zombies would you rate? I'm unsure if I fall in the catagory of project review, also it does depend heavily on 3rd party modules namely PIL and Cryptography modules. But I think I have valid reasons for using those.

Comment: Sometimes it's just the title - if it reads like a bunch of tags slammed together it's less likely to be clicked on (citation needed). I'd try to come up with something punny that hints at *Steganography is the art of hiding messages in (images, videos or even audio)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) for that: [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915).

I'd start with providing more context to your question. Most of the readers won't recognize what steganography is. Those that do will wonder why you wrote your own version instead of sticking with something that's already available.

In my opinion, fixing those 2 points and re-reading your own question with 'how will this look for an outsider' in mind should get you a long way.

Comment: Thank you for redirecting me to the faq, that was unkown to me. If I edit my question will that be allowed to hopefully get a better answer? Seems I should've asked first how to improve my question and afterwards put up a bounty for it.

Comment: @Ludisposed I think you got here just in time. There's still time left to improve your question AND get answers before the bounty expires.

Answer (score 5):

1. Your titles split up the code and make it so reviewers have to copy and paste a lot. This also makes the question longer than needs be, and so is generally a turn off for myself.

   Otherwise your question's pretty small. And looks ok to me.
2. Other than the mini-title code breakers it looks fine.
3. Yes.
4. You're not allowed to [answer invalidate](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1763), which the asker of the other question did. You've done fine.